# Как проверить на наличие дочернего селектора через jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Например есть блок:

```
<ul class="lol">
    <li>
        <span>
            <span class="show">Показывать блок</span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>
            <span class="show">
                Показывать блок
            </span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>
            <span class="show">
                Показывать блок
            </span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

И нужно у ul выбрать span с class="show", и его показать, а остальные скрыть. Их расположение рандомное.
Код ниже не работает, он почему то применяет ко всем css block, неважно, есть ли класс show, или нет, в чем может быть проблема?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($(".lol").children(".show").length > 0) {
        $(this).css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
    }
    //});
});
```

Вариаций пробовала много, и с .show(), и с .hide(), и циклом пыталась, все равно всем прописывает "блок"...

Comment: Что вам нужно скрывать? span или li?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov именно li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, что делает ваш код

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  // создали обработчик события document.onready
    // здесь this === document 
    // если у элемента $(".lol") есть дети с классом ".show"
    if ($(".lol").children(".show").length > 0) {
        // то установить стиль  всему документу!!!
        $(this).css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Как нужно: выбрать нужные элементы и скрыть. Это делается таким кодом

```
$(".lol > li:not(:has(span.show))").hide();
```

"выбрать все `li`, которые являются непосредственными детьми элемента с классом `lol`, причем такие, у которых НЕТ дочерних `span` с классом `show`"

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".lol > li:not(:has(span.show))").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="lol">
    <li>
        <span>
            <span class="show">Показывать блок</span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>
            <span class="show">
                Показывать блок
            </span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>
            <span class="show">
                Показывать блок
            </span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ну вот да, но как тогда быть? Я пыталась через .each перебрать каждый элемент, что бы он индивидуально проверял. Но все равно эффект тот же((

Comment: @Дарья Я обновил ответ

Comment: хах, вы гений! Спасибо большое, моя логика двигалась не в том направлении!))